# Need Guidance with 'LOAD DATA INFILE'

Tags: mysql, linux

I have created a file called '/root/jyoti/test.txt' with below contents:

```
tail /root/jyoti/test.txt
20,'Daily','Complete'
21,'Daily','Complete'
22,'Daily','in-progress'
```

Then tried to following query to load the data in a mysql table say 'test'

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | testname  | testtype   |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  2 | Daily     | Complete   |


mysql> load data infile '/root/jyoti/test.txt' into table accounts fields terminated by ',' (id,testname,testtype);
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/root/jyoti/test.txt' (Errcode: 13)
```

From another post I found someone recommended to use 'load data local infile' instead of 'load data infile', but this too failed with error.

```
mysql> load data local infile '/root/jyoti/test.txt' into table accounts fields terminated by ',' (id,testname,testtype);
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I am using following MySql version:-

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l
```

The file have below permission:

```
stat /root/jyoti/test.txt
  File: `/root/jyoti/test.txt'
  Size: 67              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: de00b6d1h/3724588753d   Inode: 554931      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-06-16 12:33:34.122226597 +0530
Modify: 2014-06-16 12:33:34.122226597 +0530
Change: 2014-06-16 12:33:34.488226595 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable loading local files with:

```
--local-infile=1
```

when you launch the mysql client. It is normally disabled by default.

Comment: Can you give me the exact steps to do this. Any working snippet will be more helpful. I tried to login mysql using option "--local-infile=1", but still it did not help.